# How can I tell if the classification Module I build in Weka correct or wrong?

Tags: weka

how can I tell if the classification model I build in Weka is correct or wrong?  What helps me find my mistakes while building classification modules?

Answer (score 0):

In machine learning there is no such thing as totally correct or totally wrong. Your classifier makes decisions: some of them are correct, some of them are wrong. Quality of classifier is a ratio of correct answers to wrong ones. So you take a test set with known answers, apply the classifier on it and check how much correct answers it gives. The test set must not be part of learning set because otherwise you will not detect overfitting.

Comment: I have built many modules using many different classifiers; I have applied SMOTE/Randomize because of the imbalance class;however, in each module I build I get the same result of ROC area .50 and under the Confusion Matrix does not show the incorrect classified instances.  I want to know what the problem is? Am I doing something wrong? I am totally new to Weka and have no experience in this software.  Many thanks for your great help.